# Setup cron for order emails

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, cron, order-email

I'm using Magento's new 1.9.1 theme and I found that the order emails were not send. I found out this was caused because in the new edition you need to schedule a cron to send the mails.

This **cron.php** was already present in the root

```
// Change current directory to the directory of current script
chdir(dirname(__FILE__));

require 'app/Mage.php';

if (!Mage::isInstalled()) {
    echo "Application is not installed yet, please complete install wizard first.";
    exit;
}

// Only for urls
// Don't remove this
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = str_replace(basename(__FILE__), 'index.php',     
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] = str_replace(basename(__FILE__), 'index.php',    
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);

Mage::app('admin')->setUseSessionInUrl(false);

umask(0);

$disabledFuncs = explode(',', ini_get('disable_functions'));
$isShellDisabled = is_array($disabledFuncs) ? in_array('shell_exec',   
$disabledFuncs) : true;
$isShellDisabled = (stripos(PHP_OS, 'win') === false) ? $isShellDisabled : true;

try {
    if (stripos(PHP_OS, 'win') === false) {
        $options = getopt('m::');
        if (isset($options['m'])) {
            if ($options['m'] == 'always') {
                $cronMode = 'always';
            } elseif ($options['m'] == 'default') {
                $cronMode = 'default';
            } else {
                Mage::throwException('Unrecognized cron mode was defined');
         }
     } else if (!$isShellDisabled) {
        $fileName = basename(__FILE__);
        $baseDir = dirname(__FILE__);
        shell_exec("/bin/sh $baseDir/cron.sh $fileName -mdefault 1 > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
        shell_exec("/bin/sh $baseDir/cron.sh $fileName -malways 1 > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
        exit;
    }
}

    Mage::getConfig()->init()->loadEventObservers('crontab');
    Mage::app()->addEventArea('crontab');

    if ($isShellDisabled) {
        Mage::dispatchEvent('always');
        Mage::dispatchEvent('default');
    } else {
        Mage::dispatchEvent($cronMode);
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::printException($e);
    exit(1);
}
```

I've done some research on Google, and as far as I can understand only the following line has to be added

```
*/5 * * * * wget -O /dev/null -q http://www.YOURDOMAIN.com/PATH_TO_MAGENTO/cron.php > /dev/null
```

Does this line need to be added to `cron.php`? And is that all it takes to send the emails?

Comment: why you need the order email  at cron

Comment: @AmitBera since Magento 1.9.1. the mails aren't send directly anymore but are being queued

Comment: i dont think so.. even in 1.9.1 order mails are going fine without any cron

Comment: @TheMagentoKid my mails weren't working. I found a thread here saying they are queued now, checked the release notes and it is also stated there

Comment: find the answer i have added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**THIS DEACTIVATES THE QUEUE COMPLETELY, but solves the issue!**

I have met with this issue before. to solve

1. copy file in `app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\order.php` to `app\code\local\Mage\Sales\Model\order.php`
2. open in an editor
3. Find this code

   `$mailer->setQueue($emailQueue)->send();`

replace it with `$mailer->send();` and save.

4. also make sure, you have added emails in sales email tab in `system => configuration`.

Good luck. Let me know if the problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

The line in question needs to be added to your cron scheduler. Using SSH you should be able to use `crontab -e` and it will prompt you to select your appropriate editor and insert the line at the end of the file.

Alternatively on servers with some kind of control panel (cPanel, Plesk etc) you may have an option to put it in via the management tool for those applications using the same format, or alternatively by putting the command in (`wget -O /dev/null -q http://www.YOURDOMAIN.com/PATH_TO_MAGENTO/cron.php`) and setting the time intervals which should match the first element.

If you have server access, I would reccomend using cron.sh rather than the cron.php as this allows you to run complex tasks under cron without impacting on load on the web server process.

To use this you would set it up like the following:

`*/5 * * * * php /path/to/magento/website/cron.sh`